# how to change portlet:renderURL dynamically?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

```
<portlet:renderURL var="reportURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/htmlreport/report.html" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

above is my render portlet url .my question is how can i change the value="/htmlreport/report.html" dynamically?

is there any way to do it?

```
 createRenderURL() { alert("hiiii"); AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) { alert("hiiii"); var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL(); renderURL .setParameter("jspPage","/htmlreport/report.html"); renderURL .setPortletId("eMenuAdvertise_WAR_eMenuAdvertiseportlet"); alert(renderURL.toString()); $("#mydiv").load(renderURL.toString()); alert(""); }); }
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding, what exactly you need. You can add parameters to the page context and use that parameter like this: <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="${parameterName}" />

Comment: What does dynamically mean in this case? Can you give us an example as to when & where should the URL change?

Comment: dynamaic means the  value="/htmlreport/report.html" in that the path of the html page will never come static..it will generate some html page name on button click and i want that name of html page in value appending with /htmlreport/generated htmlfile name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could generate the renderUrl using liferay javascript functions, like this:

```
AUI().use("liferay-portlet-url", function(a) {
   var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
   var value = document.getElementById('page');
   portletURL.setParameter("jspPage", value);
});
```

Comment: i have done like this as i have update my question at the end please see it. but nothing execute after  AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) this line

Comment: try to put AUI.ready() outside the createRenderURL function, directly inside a <aui:script> block

Comment: but my aui tag is not working i think ...i dont know why.but whenever i run this portlet in my custom theme its not working but in classic theme of liferay its working fine